# MFC CListCtrl OnToolTipNotify

Tags: c++, mfc

I'm trying to override OnToolTipNotify for the CListCtrl to have tooltips that support more than 80 characters.  I want the tooltips to appear for specific cells. I've seen a bunch of posts related to this, but none have completely helped me understand the best way to do this.  Here is what I have so far, but I'm concerned with the wide char code that uses T2W.  I read T2W uses memory off the stack and when the function returns it will be cleaned up. So, lpszText will become invalid. This seems to work though and I cannot find another way to do it.

```
BOOL CListCtrlEx::OnToolTipNotify(UINT tooldId, NMHDR* notifMsg, LRESULT result)
{
    USES_CONVERSION;
    TOOLTIPTEXTA* tttA = reinterpret_cast<TOOLTIPTEXTA*>(notifMsg);
    TOOLTIPTEXTW* tttW = reinterpret_cast<TOOLTIPTEXTW*>(notifMsg);
    ...
    int row, col;
    cellHitTest(row, col);
    CString tipStr;

    // Note getTooltip() returns const ref to cell's tooltip string
    if (-1 < row && -1 < col)
        tipStr = m_Data[row]->colvals[col]->getTooltip();

    if (tipStr.IsEmpty()) return FALSE;

    if (TTN_NEEDTEXTA == notifMsg->code)
    {
        tttA->lpszText = tipStr.GetBuffer();
        tttA->hinst = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        // Question: Is this a problem?  Will the buffer pointed to
        // by tttW->lpszText be deleted after this function ends  
        // making the pointer invalid?
        tttW->lpszText = T2W(tipStr.GetBuffer());
        tttW->hinst = 0;
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: I used `ON_NOTIFY_REFLECT(LVN_GETINFOTIP, OnGetInfoTip)` and `void CMyListCtrlEx::OnGetInfoTip(NMHDR* pNMHDR, LRESULT* pResult)`

Answer (score 0):

I tried to understand your question with my best efforts. All you are saying that `CString` can be used, but the wide conversion cannot be used directly without `T2W` conversion macro. If this is the question, you can simply use `CStringW` - assign `tipStr` to a variable of this type, and pass it to `lpszText`.

But, I see problem with your code - you are assuming that if `code` is not `TTN_NEEDTEXTA`, it must be `TTN_NEEDTEXTW`- this assumption is wrong.

EDIT: [From this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28885/CListCtrl-and-Displaying-a-Tooltip), I found out that you need to allocate it dynamically. Hope this helps!

> If using the TTN_NEEDTEXT message handler and one wants to display
>   tooltip longer than 80 characters, then one must allocate the wanted
>   text buffer and set the TOOLTIPTEXT::lpszText pointer to this
>   text-buffer in the message handler (one has to deallocate this text
>   buffer manually):

Comment: This was no help.  What you say is a problem in my code is similar to MSDN documentation - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sa23xtsw.aspx.  Note that example uses szText, which has the 80 character limit.  I'm trying to use lpszText to allow tooltips greater than 80 characters.

Comment: Edited the answer. I see that `tagNMTTDISPINFOW::szText` is defined to be `80` size array/

Comment: I've seen that article, but don't understand when/where/how to deallocate the text buffer.  Is there another callback when the tooltip message disappears where I can deallocate? I assume I could use `tipStr.AllocSysString()` for the allocation in the above code in place of `T2W`?

Comment: @user2971092: There is no callback that lets you know, when the tooltip no longer requires the information, and that it can be deleted. The best you can do is allocate a static array, copy your strings to it, and set that as the *lpszText* member. Alternatively, use a `CStringA`/`CStringW` class member that stores the text, and assign the return value of `operator LPCSTR`/`LPCWSTR` to the *lpszText* member. That way you can use arbitrarily sized strings, and not have to worry about memory leaks.

Comment: @IInspectable: lpszText is a LPWSTR (for wide), so I cannot assign a LPCWSTR to it.

Comment: @user2971092: You'll need a `const_cast`. This is safe, as the system will only ever read from the data provided by you. The *lpszText* member isn't declared `const`, since the `NMTTDISPINFO` structure used to set tooltip data is also used to query for information. As a consequence, const-correctness often suffers in the Windows API.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I use:
tiptext is the CString containing the text I want to show
m_pchTip and m_pwchTip are members of my list control.

```
    if(m_pchTip != NULL)
    {
        delete[] m_pchTip;
        m_pchTip = nullptr;
    }

    if(m_pwchTip != NULL)
    {
        delete[] m_pwchTip;
        m_pwchTip = nullptr;
    }

        if(pNMHDR->code == TTN_NEEDTEXTA)
        {
            TOOLTIPTEXTA* pTTTA = (TOOLTIPTEXTA*)pNMHDR;
            m_pchTip = new char[tiptext.GetLength() + 1];
            lstrcpyn(m_pchTip,tiptext,tiptext.GetLength() + 1);
            m_pchTip[tiptext.GetLength()] = 0;
            pTTTA->lpszText = m_pchTip;
        }
        else
        {
            TOOLTIPTEXTW* pTTTW = (TOOLTIPTEXTW*)pNMHDR;
            m_pwchTip = new WCHAR[tiptext.GetLength() + 1];
            _mbstowcsz(m_pwchTip,tiptext,tiptext.GetLength() + 1);
            m_pwchTip[tiptext.GetLength()] = 0;
            pTTTW->lpszText = (WCHAR*)m_pwchTip;
        }
```

Comment: Your answer looks promising.  I'll give it a try.  For the TTN_NEEDTEXTA case wouldn't `pTTTA->lpszText = tiptext.GetBuffer();` be sufficient?

Comment: In my case `tiptext` is a const ref to the cell's member, so I think it may be all right.  But now I'm questioning the need to support `TTN_NEEDTEXTA`.  `pNMHDR->code` always equals `TTN_NEEDTEXTW` for me, so I'm not sure how I would even test the `TTN_NEEDTEXTA` case.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I ended up doing. Since I could not find a case in my applications where I need to handle the `TTN_NEEDTEXTA == notifMsg->code` case I'm not supporting it.  I removed `ON_NOTIFY_EX_RANGE(TTN_NEEDTEXTA...)` from the message map and in `CListCtrlEx::OnToolTipNotify` I return FALSE if `TTN_NEEDTEXTA == notifMsg->code`. I will revisit it when I better understand ANSI vs. UNICODE.

In my cell class I changed the `CString tooltip` member to `CStringW` as @IInspectable suggested.  The CListCtrlEx::OnToolTipNotify function has access to the cell's CStringW member, so I set `lpszText = const_cast<LPWSTR>((LPCWSTR)m_Data[row]->colvals[col]->tooltip)`.